# Remote Dekstop software on Linux that could be installed without root?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop

Is there any remote desktop software(like x2go, nomachine) that can be installed without `root` permissions?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to use the client or the server without root? Which system(s)? Have you check any of those to see if they provide a static version or an appimage for example?

Comment: "By default, Ubuntu comes with Remmina remote desktop client with support for VNC and RDP protocols" --[source](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/access-remote-desktop#1-overview). I believe [Boxes](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Boxes) ships with Fedora, or at least it did at one point.

Comment: Server is based on Gentoo.